# Xcode Instruments - Allocations missing window

Tags: xcode, instruments, xcode-instruments

I'm running Xcode 8.3.1 and I'm having some trouble figuring out how to get this window in Allocations: 
[image] .

The one I have looks like this: 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is no longer in the right panel in Instruments. It is now located under "Recording Options..." on Instruments' "File" menu, yielding:

[image]

And the "Mark generation" is located at the bottom of the window while the profiling is taking place, having selected "Details" » "Generations" in the main panel while the "Allocations" tool is selected:

[image]